# Ideas for filling up large nook

Tags: cabinets, shelving, recessed-lighting

I have a rather large nook ( 13 feet wide ) in my basement which will have cabinets and countertop. ( see attached picture ).

My two problems are :

1. Since largest stock countertop is 10 feet wide, I will be left with about 3 feet space. Assuming I split this into two 1.5 wide space; what can I put on both sides ? Countertop cabinets ? Shelves ?
2. There is a recessed light in center of nook. I want to install track lighting. Are there any sort of adapters or connector available which can simply be hooked into recessed light holder.

[image]
Nook

Comment: a diagram showing a plan view might help.

Comment: Please ask just one question per post. We're not a discussion forum, and "any ideas" questions usually get closed as either too broad, opinion-based, or design-related, all of which are off-topic here. [Read more](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Why wouldn't you order (or build) a countertop to fit? They aren't substantially more expensive to order, and plastic laminate is fairly easy to work with. You might post a question asking about that.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want countertop the whole way, they can be spliced/jointed. The fancy stuff by fancy installers with fancy glues can approach a seamless appearance (for fancy prices) while typical sheet goods will have a visible seam, which is not a big deal if fancy prices don't appeal. Depending on the purpose of the countertop you could do something like hide the seam under a built-in/on cutting board.

Then again, perhaps you need a basement fridge or freezer, 3 feet taken care of easily.

This slides off towards (off-topic) decorating advice pretty quickly once you get out of the "how to do the whole length as countertop" question which is somewhat on-topic.

Replace the light with a junction box for your new lighting.

Comment: Yep. Almost any kitchen has at least one splice, and if done carefully they're nearly invisible. A Forstner bit and some countertop bolts and you're in business.